# Template Method within Template class definition does not match declaration

Tags: c++, templates

I have made a template class LinkedList of template class T and within this class, I want to implement a function enqueue that takes data of a general type D and calls the T constructor on with the data D as the parameter.

**This is the definition of my class:**

```
template<class T>

struct Node {
    struct Node *_nextNode;
    struct Node *_prevNode;
    T *_value;
    int _location;
};

template<class T>
class LinkedList    {

private:
    Node<T> *_firstNode;
    Node<T> *_lastNode;
    int _size;

public:
    LinkedList<T>();
    LinkedList<T>(const int size);
    ~LinkedList<T>();

    template<typename D>
    bool enqueue(D &newData);
    bool dequeue();
    T* find(const int location);

};
```

**And this is where I declare the function enqueue:**

```
template<class T, typename D>
bool LinkedList<T>::enqueue(D &newData) {
    Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>;
    newNode->_value = new T(newData);
    newNode->_location = _lastNode->_location + 1;
    _lastNode->_nextNode = newNode;
    newNode->_prevNode = _lastNode;
    _lastNode = newNode;
    _lastNode->_nextNode = NULL;
    _size++;

    return true;
}
```

**When trying to compile I get:**

```
LinkedList.cpp:76:6: error: prototype for ‘bool LinkedList<T>::enqueue(D&)’ does not match any in class ‘LinkedList<T>’
 bool LinkedList<T>::enqueue(D &newData) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
LinkedList.cpp:29:7: error: candidate is: template<class T> template<class D> bool LinkedList<T>::enqueue(D&)
  bool enqueue(D &newData);
```

Ignore the actual content of the enqueue function, I have not changed that yet from my previous implementation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define your function body as:

```cpp
template <typename T>
template <typename D>
bool LinkedList<T>::enqueue (D& newData) {
  // ...
}
```

Also, `const D&` is probably cleaner. It would be even better to use perfect forwarding, to allow passing any kind of reference type:

```cpp
template <typename T>
template <typename D>
bool LinkedList<T>::enqueue (D&& newData) {
  // ...
  newNode->_value = new T (std::forward<D>(newData));
}
```

This can also be made to work with an arbitrary number of parameters to the constructor:

```cpp
template <typename T>
template <typename... D>
bool LinkedList<T>::enqueue (D&&... newData) {
  // ...
  newNode->_value = new T (std::forward<D>(newData)...);
}
```

Additionally, your code isn't exception-safe. If the `T` constructor throws an exception, the `newNode` instance is never freed, causing a memory leak.

Also, don't use `NULL`, but use `nullptr` if possible (i.e. if you can use C++11).

Comment: So what is the reason that template <class T, typename D> doesn't work? What is the distinction between that and template <class T>, template <typename D>?

Comment: Because that fix does work, but I do not understand the difference. In terms of your other suggestions, I definitely appreciate that. I am a student with little experience in industry code so working to improve my code is always something I strive for.

Comment: This is just how the C++ syntax works. If you have a member function template within a class template, you need two distinct `template <...>` directives. This makes it easier to tell the class template parameters and the function template parameters apart. Very laudable, keep learning ;-)

Comment: Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer with the checkmark if it solves your question :)

Comment: You can read the standard language in [temp.mem](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem), but asking for the motivation behind the standard is really a different question.