# Defining a method with class-level and method-level template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I've declared a class like this:

**snapshot.h**

```
template<typename F>
class Snapshot
{
public:
    template<typename T> void write(T field);
};

#include "snapshot.templates.cpp"
```

**snapshot.templates.cpp**

```
template<typename F, typename T>
void Snapshot<F>::write(T field)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

But the compiler gives the error `declaration is incompatible with function template "void Snapshot<F>::write(T)"`

What is the correct syntax for specifying the two template parameters `F` and `T` in the definition of `write()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template Method within Template class definition does not match declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880487/template-method-within-template-class-definition-does-not-match-declaration)

Comment: If you intend to separate a template's declarations and implementations into two files with the implementations included in the header file, then I would recommend not using the `.cpp` extension for the implementation file. `.cpp` conventionally indicates a source file that should be compiler as translation unit and build systems/IDEs may handle it this way automatically, resulting in errors or ODR violations. Common extensions for template implementation files are `.tpp`, `.tcc` and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264656/c-template-implementation-file-extension-convention).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a template function which is a member of a template class you need to define it like this:

```cpp
template<typename F>
template<typename T>
void Snapshot<F>::write(T field)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

Check it out [live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880487/template-method-within-template-class-definition-does-not-match-declaration)

**UPDATE**

Please, note that you can't split implementation of template class into header and source file because the compiler needs to have access to the implementation of the methods in order to instantiate them with the passed argument. If the implementation is not in the header, it is not accessible to the compiler.